# How to determine the ojdbc driver version of my weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, ojdbc

I am using weblogic 12.1.3 and could see that both ojdbc6 and 7 jars are available in path

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc_12.1.0\
```

I am trying to understand the ojdbc version  that my weblogic server is used to connect to database. I tried the below command, but both worked out for me.

```
java -jar ojdbc6.jar -getversion
Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Tue_Apr_22_08:54:06_PDT_2014
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Tue Aug 15 14:25:00 CDT 2017

java -jar ojdbc7.jar -getversion
Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.1 compiled with JDK7 on Tue_Apr_22_08:56:40_PDT_2014
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Tue Aug 15 14:25:20 CDT 2017
```

Is there a way to find the same from weblogic console? if yes, please advise that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default driver for Oracle 12.1.3 is ojdbc7.jar.

See [JDBC Drivers Installed with WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCA/third_party_drivers.htm#JDBCA232)

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to confirm it